# Исключение крайнего значения

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста, есть много отсортированных списков, например [1,2,3,7] или [1,6,7,8].
Нужно каким то образом выкинуть из каждого списка значение, которое наиболее отличается от среднего(наверное, арифметического). Как это сделать?

Comment: А в чем у вас проблемы? Судя по вашему профилю вы знакомы с Pandas и Numpy. Задача вроде бы не архисложная... PS как быть если есть 2+ одинаковых значения которые максимально удалены от среднего?

Comment: знаком то да, но заклинило, была идея перебирать список и каждое значение сравнивать со средним, но даже в голове получается слишком много строчек, не покидает ощущение что все можно сделать элегантно, вот и решил спросить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет смысла сравнивать все значения, надо сравнить только крайние, т.к. список отсортирован, то у них будет большая разница со средним

```py
def foo(arr):  
    average = sum(arr) / len(arr)  
    if average - arr[0] > arr[-1] - average:  
        return arr[1:]  
    else:  
        return arr[:-1]

arr = [1, 3, 4, 7]
new_arr = foo(arr)
```

Comment: элегантное решение (если автору надо избавиться строго от одного значения)!

Comment: вот о таком я и говорил, именно) благодарю

Comment: @JohnGalt, Т.е. из `[1,2,3,4,5,10,10]` надо получить `[1,2,3,4,5,10]`?

Comment: исходя из задачи, ответ не очевиден на 100%, но думаю, да